# get posts by id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, posts

I want to get posts by id. Id's are in array. I am using this code but now working.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'job_listing', 
    'post__in' => array( 311, 312 ) 
));

print_r($the_query); //this doesn't print any data

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: So when that is run nothing is being displayed?

Comment: The fact that `print_r($the_query);` is not printing **anything** is really weird... Are you using namespaces in your code?

Comment: have done it, thanks for your time

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) as it takes the same arguments as [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

To pass it the IDs, use `'post__in' => array(311, 312)` (only takes arrays).

Below is the example.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'job_listing',
    'post__in' => array(311, 312)
);

$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($posts as $p) :
    //post!
endforeach;
```